# how to add the total of a group in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

how can i add the total of a group ?

```
Group 1 
     accnt      amount     type
     -----------------------------
     xxx        100.00     project
     yyy         50.00     project
     zzz         50.00     project
     -----------------------------
Total Group 1   200.00

Group 2
     accnt      amount     type
     -----------------------------
     aaa         75.00     nope
     bbb         75.00     nope
     -----------------------------
Total Group 2   150.00
```

Now, i want to get the total of the group like `group 1 + group 2 = 350` how to do that in crystal report ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click your amount field and select Insert Summary... Calculate SUM ... Summary Location should be Grand Total(Report Footer)

Comment: i'l try this mate.. :)